# R - for loop to compare columns across the same data set

Tags: r, for-loop, compare

I have a list of certain economic indicators for several countries for 2 sequential years.  Country is a row, each economic indicator is a column for each year (V1_2015 and V1_2016 are the variables I want to compare.

I want to loop through to compare the variables.  Fortunately, the columns are in the correct order so I think I can loop through.  I am not a pro at for loops but thought I was pretty close...

```
Economics_2_years <- as.data.frame(cbind(
                    CountryID = c(9999,8888,7777,6666,5555,4444,3333,2222,1111,1234),
                    V1_2015 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                    V2_2015 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                    V3_2015 = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                    V1_2016 = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                    V2_2016 = c(9,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,2,2),
                    V3_2016 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))


Economics_Change <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 4))
Economics_Change$V1 <- Economics_Change$CountryID

for (i in 2:4){
for (j in 5:7){
for (k in 2:4)
  Economics_Change[,k]  <- Economics_2_years[,i]==Economics_2_years[,j]
```

}
}

The purpose is to store in 'Economics_Change' whether or not the variables have changed.  And if they have changed, which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is a vectorised programming language so instead of a for loop you can do this:

```
    Economics_Change$V1 <- Economics_2_years$V1_2015==Economics_2_years$V1_2016
    Economics_Change$V2 <- Economics_2_years$V2_2015==Economics_2_years$V2_2016
    Economics_Change$V3 <- Economics_2_years$V3_2015==Economics_2_years$V3_2016
```

Or if there is many of columns, but there are somewhat consistent with their names you can do:

```
cols <- lapply(1:3, function(var_number) {
  Economics_2_years[paste("V", var_number, "_2015", sep="")] == Economics_2_years[paste("V", var_number, "_2016", sep="")]
})
 results_df <- do.call("cbind", cols)
```

If the names are more complicated then V + number + _year or the numbers are with gaps here is a example how you can deal with it.

```
Economics_2_years <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  CountryID = c(9999,8888,7777,6666,5555,4444,3333,2222,1111,1234),
  VVV1_2015 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  VE7_2015 = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  V10_2015 = c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  VVV1_2016 = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
  VE7_2016 = c(9,1,2,5,3,2,1,2,2,2),
  V10_2016 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))


colnames(Economics_2_years) %>% regmatches(., gregexpr("^(.*?)_", .)) %>% unlist() %>% unique() -> names_roots
cols <- lapply(names_roots, function(root) {
  Economics_2_years[paste(root, "2015", sep="")] == Economics_2_years[paste(root, "2016", sep="")]
})
results_df <- do.call("cbind", cols)
```

Comment: Pawel - this is correct and one of the routes I took; however, I have 85 columns per year.  That is why I was hoping to leverage a loop.

Comment: I understand I edited my answer. What about lapply? For small n it is faster than for loop and seems more elegant. I assume that the column names are in some manner similar, so you can dynamically change column names and extend my example to any number of columns. If you column names aren't so simple as "V_number_year" than you can always get all your colnames, extract the "V" part, take unique vector of them, and adapt easily to my answer with `lapply`.

Comment: One more question - if I follow this example, I get an error if there is a gap in numbers.  I get an error if I have V1.x, v25.x, v1.y, v25.y.  Maybe I do not understand lapply like I thought... In the above example, I would assume lapply(1:2, ...) would work, but I get the "Error in `[.data.frame`(Conditions_ALL_Wide3, paste("HCC", var_number,  : 
  undefined columns selected "

Comment: Ok as I understand the problem is that the numbers are not going like 1,2,3,4,... but 1,25,33,100 etc. So you can't use `:` to generate the part of column names. Ok But still if they are consistent in the manner that there is "V", "some number", " _" and after that year part, then as I said you can extract the first part with regular expressions. I will add example to my response.